# XSL selective copy

Tags: xslt, copy, match

I have this XML file:

```
<bases>
<marker>
       <name>Main</nane>
       <city>Hartford</city>
       <tag>current</tag>
</marker>
<marker>
       <name>Secondary</nane>
       <city>Boston</city>
       <tag>none</tag>
</marker>
<marker>
       <name>Tertiary</nane>
       <city>Bedford</city>
</marker>
</bases>
```

I want to copy only those markers where the tag element matches "current". So, the output would be this:

```
<bases>
<marker>
       <name>Main</nane>
       <city>Hartford</city>
       <tag>current</tag>
</marker>
</bases>
```

I'm an XSLT novice and I can't figure it out. Help, please.

Comment: Please ask a **specific** question about a difficulty you encountered when trying to accomplish this. Otherwise it looks like you're just looking for someone to do your work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it simply like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  
  <!-- Remove all marker elements where element tag value is not 'current' -->
  <xsl:template match="marker[not(tag='current')]"/>
  
  <!-- Identity template -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here : https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/aiynev/2

Comment: Thank you. That got me a long way. However, I now notice that many of my marker elements do not have a "tag" and they appear in the result. I modified the example XML in my post above to reflect this. How do I suppress these from appearing in the output?

Comment: @EdS. See my updated answer.

Comment: @EdS. You're welcome. If this answers your question please mark the answer as accepted.